# match pattern not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match strings that only have a, g, c or t in them (insensitive)
so the string: "AAaaatCCCc" is valid while "catb" is not.
this is my function:

```
var pattern = "/^[agct]+$/i";
if (!this.inputSeq.value.trim().match(pattern)){
    this.errMsg = "Invalid input sequence -must contain only a,g,c or t"
    updateErrorBox(this.errMsg);
}
```

When i enter valid strings i'm still getting the error message

Comment: `pattern` should be a regular expression, not a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions. Also if you just want to test whether the expression matches, use `.test`: `pattern.test(this.inputSeq.value.trim())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the quotes from the regex literal:

```
var pattern = "/^[agct]+$/i";
```

To:

```
var pattern = /^[agct]+$/i;
```

There is an implicitly conversion

> **regexp**
>
> A regular expression object. If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(obj).

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

But it's not working, because you have flags in the pattern and slashes: `/../`.

```
var pattern = "^[agct]+$";
... .match(pattern)
```

Could work due the implicit conversion, but case sensitive because of the missing `i` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input text is being picked up correctly, a console log of its value might help isolate the issue, this code should work:

```
if (!this.inputSeq.value.match(/^\s*[agct]+\s*$/i)) {
    this.errMsg = "Invalid input sequence -must contain only a,g,c or t"
    updateErrorBox(this.errMsg);
}
```

You were using a literal sting instead of a regular expression for the pattern hence the error messages.